# Image does not change after downloading the file (VueJs and FileReader)

Tags: image, vue.js, filereader, cropperjs

I have an input type file. After loading a picture, I assign a value to my data property "imgSrc"

```js
methods:{
  setImage(e){
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let isValidImageWidthAndHeight = true;
    let $self = this;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = event.target.result;

        image.onload = function(){

            if(this.width < 256 || this.height < 256){
                isValidImageWidthAndHeight = false;
            }

            if(isValidImageWidthAndHeight){
                $self.imgSrc = image.src; // here i change this prop
            }else{
                Vue.swal({
                    title: 'Ошибка',
                    text: 'Минимальные размеры картинки 256 х 256',
                    type: 'error',
                });
            $('.userUploadButton').val('');
        }
      };
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

after first load all ok like this screen - http://joxi.ru/KAxn6yZsMxn5Wm

But after the next upload, the picture does not change - http://joxi.ru/MAj38WvF4pRPar

Comment: How are you binding `imgSrc` to the `src` attribute? Like this: `<img :src='imgSrc'></img>`?

Comment: no, it is base64 encode

Answer (score 0):

```
$self.$refs.cropper.replace(image.src);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.